# systemctl docker.service setting not taking into effect

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I am running Docker 18.03.5 on Ubuntu 18.04.1

#### Environment

```
$ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.5
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.12
 Git commit:        633a0ea838
 Built:             Wed Nov 13 07:29:52 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.5
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.12.12
  Git commit:       633a0ea838
  Built:            Wed Nov 13 07:28:22 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.2.10
  GitCommit:        b34a5c8af56e510852c35414db4c1f4fa6172339
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc8+dev
  GitCommit:        3e425f80a8c931f88e6d94a8c831b9d5aa481657
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

#### Docker.Service

Using `sudo systemctl edit docker.service`, I have this in my override.conf

```
# /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/override.conf
[Service]
#ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemom -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd --group beijing -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

### Docker Socket Wrong Permission

After running

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo systemctl restart docker
```

I still see the Docker socket defaults to the **docker** group rather than the **beijing** group

What is causing the docker.service settings to not take into effect?

Comment: I notice, are you missing the tag [Service] on you override?

Comment: And... I'm not sure but I thing that you must override this one /etc/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/docker.socket too.

Comment: @matiferrigno thanks, I have added the complete content of the docker service file